# ASP.NET MVC How to output FileContent from within a controller action and continue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, fileresult

I am fairly new to MVC and want to know what the correct approach is - when a form is submitted the Edit ActionResult is executed, once the data is saved, I want to generate a file and send to the browser for download but also continue to another action.

The file is sent to the browser but no further processing occurs in the controller, because I use return RedirectToActions. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, InvoiceFormData formData)  
{ 
  ...    
  return base.RedirectToAction("ReturnPdf", new { id = 99 });

  // More processing...ideally...then

  return base.RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
}

public FileResult ReturnPdf(int? id)
{
  ...
  return output; // writes file output and prompts user to download
}
```

Comment: If you want the user to be directed to another page when clicking a download link, could you first navigate to the page and then, in javascript, make an async call to your ReturnPdf action which will prompt the user to download a file. Or, do you only want to redirect the user if they accept the download?

Comment: Thanks, I can understand using a link or async call in view to initiate the ReturnPdf action but I was hoping to be able to initiate it from within the controller at the time the data is saved.

Comment: I think the question is 'is it possible to download a file to the browser whilst processing within a controller action' or can it only be done from a view?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use two return statements in the same action result and expect them to both run. When you "return" it means you're returning the output and then quiting out of the action result. Therefore, you could kind of chain your actions, so rather than doing the further processing inside the Edit action result, you could move that logic into the ReturnPdf AR(since that's what's I could see in your code), then finally return the final output in whatever action result you landed on. I hope that was clear enough...

Comment: Thanks for the info, the problem is that the ReturnPDF AR because it returns a FileResult is a kind of dead end (no RedirectToAction). It seems to lend itself just to being called from a view.